# Sybase ASE 16x and .NET Core 1.1 making a SP call

Tags: asp.net-core, sybase, sap-ase

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (v 15.2).  Core 1.1 and using Sybase ASE 16.0 sp2.  I am also using the *Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient*.dll within the Sybase SDK 16.0.

```
public IEnumerable<Countries> GetCountry()
    {

        var con = new AseConnection(ConnectionString); // No Errors
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand(); // Error described below

        return null;
    }
```

the `CreateCommand()` generates, in the IDE (squiggly red line) the following:
`The type 'Db Connection is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'system.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey=b77a5c561934e089'`

I loaded per PackageManger

- *install-package System.Data.Common -version 4.1.0*, which loads but the error is still there.
- *install-package System.Data.Common -version 4.3.0*, which loads but the error is still there.
- Tried to install *install-package System.Data.Common -version 4.0.0*,
  but get an error (shown below):
- Tried to install *install-package System.Data.Common -version
  4.0.0.0*, but get the same an error above (shown below):

*Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'iKYC.API'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  System.Data.Common -version 4.0.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPacka 
   geCommand*

I have not loaded the EntityFrame work, due to this being Sybase.  Sybase is the ONLY DB I can use.

Comment: Has ANYONE successfully used Sybase with CORE?

Comment: We've been working on [this driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdoNetCore.AseClient).
To read some documentation and see a more detailed description of what it currently supports, [check it out on github](https://github.com/DataAction/AdoNetCore.AseClient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a project to test this and found that, funnily enough, if you target 
 `.net core 2.0` instead of `1.1` it will build.

*However*, this results in runtime error `System.MissingMethodException`, because the driver is looking for methods (and namespaces?) that don't yet exist in .net core.

The reason for this is that `Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll` targets .net framework 4, not .net core. It even hints at it in the filename (`AdoNet4`).

For now, it looks like this driver's not compatible with .net core. Maybe one day, when the missing methods are ported to .net core... it might work?

Luckily, there are a couple of alternatives:

1. Use the [`System.Data.Odbc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Odbc) namespace/package. `System.Data.Odbc` is currently in pre-release and looks to target `.net core 2.0+`. May not be a good fit for you if you're chained to `.net core 1.1`.

   - Personally, I've messed around with the `System.Data.Odbc` package, and while it worked with simple stuff, I had some issues. In particular, there didn't seem to be any way to get return values from stored procedures working, and the lack of support for named parameters (an `ODBC` thing I think), made it difficult to work with.
2. Use the [`AdoNetCore.AseClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdoNetCore.AseClient) namespace/package. After a lot of frustration, I bit the bullet and working on an `ADO.NET` driver which targets `.net core 1.0`, `1.1`, `2.0`, and `.net framework 4.6`. If you want to view the sources/documentation and figure out if it's the right fit for you, it's [available on github](https://github.com/DataAction/AdoNetCore.AseClient).

   - To use this driver, simply reference the package and replace `using Sybase.Data.AseClient;` with `using AdoNetCore.AseClient;`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have started using [Link][ODBC Preview Package][1] but haven't tested out the performance yet.  Will take a look at your link! [1]:https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Odbc/4.5.0-preview1-25914-04